# multiplying a row by two from one dataset, and attaching it as a separate column to another dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Suppose my data is:

```
df1 <- structure(list(country = c("Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", 
                              "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", 
                              "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", 
                              "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", 
                              "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", 
                              "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", 
                              "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", 
                              "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", 
                              "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", 
                              "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", 
                              "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", 
                              "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", 
                              "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", 
                              "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", 
                              "Denmark", "Denmark", "Denmark", "France", "France", "France", 
                              "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
                              "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
                              "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
                              "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
                              "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
                              "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
                              "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
                              "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
                              "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
                              "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
                              "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
                              "France", "France", "France", "France", "France"), year = c(1830, 
                                                                                          1831, 1832, 1833, 1834, 1835, 1836, 1837, 1838, 1839, 1840, 1841, 
                                                                                          1842, 1843, 1844, 1845, 1846, 1847, 1848, 1849, 1850, 1851, 1852, 
                                                                                          1853, 1854, 1855, 1856, 1857, 1858, 1859, 1860, 1861, 1862, 1863, 
                                                                                          1864, 1865, 1866, 1867, 1868, 1869, 1870, 1871, 1872, 1873, 1874, 
                                                                                          1875, 1876, 1877, 1878, 1879, 1880, 1881, 1882, 1883, 1884, 1885, 
                                                                                          1886, 1887, 1888, 1889, 1890, 1891, 1892, 1893, 1894, 1895, 1896, 
                                                                                          1897, 1898, 1899, 1900, 1901, 1902, 1903, 1904, 1905, 1906, 1907, 
                                                                                          1908, 1909, 1910, 1911, 1912, 1913, 1914, 1830, 1831, 1832, 1833, 
                                                                                          1834, 1835, 1836, 1837, 1838, 1839, 1840, 1841, 1842, 1843, 1844, 
                                                                                          1845, 1846, 1847, 1848, 1849, 1850, 1851, 1852, 1853, 1854, 1855, 
                                                                                          1856, 1857, 1858, 1859, 1860, 1861, 1862, 1863, 1864, 1865, 1866, 
                                                                                          1867, 1868, 1869, 1870, 1871, 1872, 1873, 1874, 1875, 1876, 1877, 
                                                                                          1878, 1879, 1880, 1881, 1882, 1883, 1884, 1885, 1886, 1887, 1888, 
                                                                                          1889, 1890, 1891, 1892, 1893, 1894, 1895, 1896, 1897, 1898, 1899, 
                                                                                          1900, 1901, 1902, 1903, 1904, 1905, 1906, 1907, 1908, 1909, 1910, 
                                                                                          1911, 1912, 1913, 1914)), row.names = c(NA, -170L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                        "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And:

```
df2 <- structure(list(y = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0.05", "0.05", "0.05", 
                        "0.05", "0.05", "0.05", "0.05", "0.05", "0.05", "0.05", "0.05", 
                        "0.05", "0.05", "0.05", "0.05", "0.6", "0.6", "0.6", "0.6", "0.6", 
                        "0.6", "0.6", "0.6", "0.6", "0.6", "0.6", "0.6", "0.6", "0.6", 
                        "0.6", "0.6", "0.6", "0.45", "0.45", "0.45", "0.45", "0.35", 
                        "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", 
                        "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", 
                        "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", 
                        "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", "0.35", "0.4", "0.45", 
                        "0.5", "0.55", "0.6", "0.65", "0.65", "0.7", "0.7", "0.75", "0.8", 
                        "0.85", "0.9", "0.95", "7.65917136766606", "7.650168700845", 
                        "7.67693714581808", "7.66387725870347", "7.70841066725737", "7.69393732550927", 
                        "7.68662133494462", "7.70481192293259", "7.70345904786717", "7.70706265537047", 
                        "7.73017479524622", "7.72046169459972", "7.71556953452021", "7.76344638872736", 
                        "7.79729127354747", "7.81278281857758", "7.82444593087762", "7.81035268372429", 
                        "7.85166117788927", "7.8991534833431", "7.94342776787637", "7.88193748927207", 
                        "7.90581031265893", "7.89989532313973", "7.89319886954461", "7.98548435673382", 
                        "7.91388671485608", "7.91753635394363", "7.89766815072691", "7.94944442025063", 
                        "7.92840602618053", "7.93200315236138", "7.95014988765202", "7.99934295271328", 
                        "7.98002359231065", "8.00269416228394", "7.99395754757357", "7.98378106897745", 
                        "7.99091546309133", "8.03657340970731", "8.06871619271478", "8.06369263426952", 
                        "8.10982627601848", "8.09529377684465", "8.11402544235676", "8.12148037475075", 
                        "8.1300590399928", "8.08978917578932", "8.11701408773731", "8.13885675069633", 
                        "8.15363748638528", "8.15478757276852", "8.18060094759445", "8.20658361432075", 
                        "8.20028826028755", "8.19560956728878", "8.22255363839696", "8.24748200428569", 
                        "8.24485939591126", "8.2495751500002", "8.2995345703326", "8.31213510764841", 
                        "8.32869258354557", "8.34069464792507", "8.35113860708615", "8.39276311303806", 
                        "8.41648848729461", "8.42595471098197", "8.42836197770962", "8.45638105201948", 
                        "8.47824444127766", "8.50673873351238", "8.51859221232995", "8.56483984488359", 
                        "8.57583938684897", "8.5816692106006", "8.59840444684106", "8.62281367327992", 
                        "8.64153246567185", "8.66681936537205", "8.68372406230387", "8.72388210465849", 
                        "8.71210186371566", "8.73809423017767", "8.78737298873188", "0.45", 
                        "0.45", "0.45", "0.45", "0.45", "0.45", "0.45", "0.45", "0.45", 
                        "0.45", "0.45", "0.45", "0.45", "0.45", "0.45", "0.45", "0.45", 
                        "0.45", "0.8", "0.8", "0.8", "0.45", "0.1", "0.1", "0.1", "0.1", 
                        "0.1", "0.1", "0.1", "0.1", "0.1", "0.15", "0.2", "0.2", "0.2", 
                        "0.2", "0.2", "0.2", "0.2", "0.35", "0.4", "0.45", "0.55", "0.6", 
                        "0.65", "0.75", "0.8", "0.85", "0.85", "0.85", "0.85", "0.85", 
                        "0.85", "0.85", "0.85", "0.85", "0.85", "0.85", "0.85", "0.85", 
                        "0.85", "0.85", "0.85", "0.85", "0.85", "0.85", "0.85", "0.85", 
                        "0.9", "0.9", "0.9", "0.9", "0.9", "0.9", "0.9", "0.9", "0.9", 
                        "0.9", "0.9", "0.9", "0.9", "0.9", "0.9", "0.9", "0.9", "7.54855597916987", 
                        "7.56320059235807", "7.64539769942863", "7.62705741701893", "7.62851762657506", 
                        "7.66152708135852", "7.64491934495886", "7.65822752616135", "7.70120018085745", 
                        "7.66387725870347", "7.73017479524622", "7.74975340627444", "7.72312009226633", 
                        "7.77064523412918", "7.80139132029149", "7.76599307940768", "7.76472054477148", 
                        "7.86557175768479", "7.79852305362521", "7.82644313545601", "7.84227877911735", 
                        "7.82364593083495", "7.88306935130575", "7.83002808253384", "7.87359778968554", 
                        "7.85438121065236", "7.89618060861549", "7.95014988765202", "8.01598781102724", 
                        "7.94732502701646", "8.01168672912785", "7.94449216393216", "8.02322468471667", 
                        "8.05356916913454", "8.06117135969092", "8.02845516411425", "8.03365842788615", 
                        "7.96901178110648", "8.05801080080209", "8.0702808933939", "8.00302866638473", 
                        "8.01532730902172", "8.10530751550515", "8.02747653086048", "8.1426451859428", 
                        "8.17103418920548", "8.08116577772543", "8.1285852003745", "8.11162807830774", 
                        "8.04334217044161", "8.12533508671429", "8.15966073706338", "8.20166019080868", 
                        "8.20166019080868", "8.18618599422608", "8.1656479252975", "8.17919979842309", 
                        "8.18451375303372", "8.1934002319521", "8.21635833238616", "8.2393294279018", 
                        "8.26281693767093", "8.28752842311176", "8.30424746507847", "8.33950090300594", 
                        "8.31752199628717", "8.36170828857584", "8.34450508359052", "8.38913252134872", 
                        "8.4424696452203", "8.43032725839458", "8.41294317004244", "8.39457347786833", 
                        "8.414717399827", "8.42024166533979", "8.43663368355782", "8.45340105832846", 
                        "8.49576524400262", "8.48755838628655", "8.52674740422105", "8.46083445774685", 
                        "8.55256033525353", "8.63070043220983", "8.62245370207373", "8.54830418644129"), t.index = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
           12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
           25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
           38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
           51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 
           64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 
           77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 
           90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 
           102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 
           113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 
           124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 
           135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 
           146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 
           157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 
           168L, 169L, 170L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
           12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
           25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
           38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
           51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 
           64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 
           77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 
           90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 
           102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 
           113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 
           124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 
           135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 
           146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 
           157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 
           168L, 169L, 170L), re.tindex = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                            1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                340L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want "Denmark" from *df1* to be attached to *df2* as a separate column under name "country" across 1:170 rows of *df2*. Then, similarly "France" has to appear across 171:340 rows of *df2*.

I would like the solution to do something with *df1*, because in reality both datasets contain many rows and categories. So, simply typing "Denmark" and "France" would be unfeasible.

I think there have to be some easy solultion to this.

Any suggestions, guys?

Comment: You'll have to provide more details. What is the logic for adding df1 data to df2? Can we simply repeat the first 85 rows twice (so we get 170 total rows) and then add those to df2? In your full data do you already have 170 rows for Denmark / France, in which case `bind_cols` would be sufficient. Is there some other logic?

Comment: I know it does sound weird, but      // Can we simply repeat the first 85 rows twice (so we get 170 total rows) and then add those to df2? //    this is basically what I am trying to do.  The final output has to be df2 with one extra column "country" in which 1:170 rows are "Denmark", 171:340 rows are "France".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the requirements you specified in the comments (that `df1` rows can just be repeated twice), this option with `bind_cols` should work:

```r
library(tidyverse)

bind_cols(
  df2, 
  df1 %>%
    group_by(country) %>%
    group_modify(~ slice(.x, rep(1:n(), times = 2)))
)
```